# Categories Help and video uploads

Tags: categories, uploads, videos

So I finally worked out how to link my posts to my pages through categories however when I click on it it comes up with Categories : Money - is there anyway to take the categories part away?

I also want to upload videos to my theme, it says I have to upgrade my plan but if I get a domain and stuff will these automatically upgrade my website?

Comment: Thank you for your post, but it sounds like you may be using wordpress.com and not a self hosted WordPress installation. WordPress.com support, as well as third-party plugins and themes are off-topic here on WPSE, so please use the support routes offered by those products for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

How you can remove *Categories:* part you will need to add the code below at the bottom of your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
    }

    return $title;
});
```

And when it comes to uploading videos and plans you have to contact your websites hosting company.